# Query to check dates, disregarding the year in Django

Tags: python, django

I am looking for an efficient way to filter by date field, without taking the year into consideration. A simplified use case would be checking whether someone's birthday is in the next two weeks.

given the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    birthdate = models.DateField()
```

if I were to do the following, it would only find users that were born this year.

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
two_weeks_time = datetime.timedelta(days=14)
Profile.objects.filter(birthdate__gte=today, birthdate__lt=two_weeks_time)
```

Is there some way of doing this in the query (also taking someone born on the 29th of February into consideration) or am I going to have to deal with that logic outside of the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude year like this.

```
Profile.objects.filter(birthdate__month__gte=today.month, birthdate__month__lt=two_weeks_time.month)
```

**EDIT**: Well you can use the [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) module to get the next month.

```
next_month = datetime.date.today() + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
```

Now you can use the `range` in a filter

```
Profile.objects.filter(birthdate__month__range=[today.month, next_month.month])
```

Comment: Thanks, i was not actually aware of that.

However, how can I make it relevant to birthdays? The above example is just going to find all birthdays in the current month (if it is less than two weeks before the end of the month) or find all birthdays in the current and next month.